# Fundamental group of quotient disk

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Consider the disk $D^{2}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. By taking out two disjoint, smaller disks within $D^{2}$, we obtain a disk of genus 2. Now consider identifying the boundaries of the two deleted circles and the original boundary of the disk. How would one go about that one may perform such an identification in two distinct ways, such that the fundamental group of the resulting spaces are not isomorphic to each other?

Comment: In the process of identifying the discs (if you're doing so by a homeomorphism), you have essentially only two ways to do it for each pair of identifications: you can either reverse the orientation, or preserve it. If you preserve the orientation with all of your identifications, you get one space; if you reverse the orientation with at least one of your identifications, you get another space.

Comment: How would one show that these two identifications aren't isomorphic? By the way, one is identifying all three boundaries to a single $S^{1}$, the boundary of the original $D^{2}$ and the boundaries of the two interior deleted regions as well